# Why doesn't my poster image show in IE9 html5 Video

Tags: internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

I have a html5 video on this page:

http://www.yellowtulipcomms.com/portfolio/global-public-speaking/

Down the bottom of the 3 right hand images.

Im using the following code

```
<video class="video-js" width="235" height="185" playbackRate="1" poster="http://www.yellowtulipcomms.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Kimia-Namadchi-STILL.jpg" controls="controls">
```

With the videos underneath and the poster image just never shows in IE9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

1. Remove the `playbackRate` attribute.
2. Add a `preload="none"` attribute

Comment: While `preload="none"` does work, it will increase the amount of time the user has to wait until the video starts (sometimes by 5-10 seconds, depending on the length of the video).

Answer (score 4):

The Image as Background only works with the preload="none" tag but for wath ist this function? for nothing. Why Opera, Firefox, Crome... can interpret this and IE can`t do?

Why i have in every WEBpage a IF IE tag? 
Why i must make every thing bad to work on IE?

Thats the solution it complets the development from microsoft.

Made a Picture with the same resolution as the video and position Absolute outside of the video tag and give a id like "video_play"
Now made a Function that fade the Picture out and play the video.

NOW you can use the preload function and it looks great and it works on IE without a black screen.

```
$("#video_play").click(function(){

    $(this).fadeOut(600);
    var video = document.getElementById("video_src");
    if (video.paused) {
       video.play();
    } else {
       video.pause();
    }

});
```

Maby you can set the Poster tag and get the attribute with javascript
and made my script full dynamic. To time is very bad... like IE....

Answer (score 3):

I had a page loading several videos, and in IE9 the poster images sometimes would appear, sometimes not. The solution was to set the poster image as a background to the video element.
Worked fine.

Comment: I've tried that, with and without a 1x1px transparent gif poster, and the background appears for a flash then disappears (in IE11). That is using preload="none", "metadata" and "auto"